# Show only <li> div's that have a checked box Ruby, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of check boxes with titles generated by a ruby model. Depending on the page, some check boxes are automatically selected. How would I hide the other li's with check boxes and titles that are not selected? Or how would I only show the li div's that are selected?

html:

```
<h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <% for store in Store.all %>
        <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[store_ids][]", store.id,    
@idea.stores.include?(store) %> <%= store.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <br />
```

inspection of checked box :

```
<input id="idea_store_ids_" type="checkbox" value="15" name="idea[store_ids][]"  
checked="checked"></input>
```

inspection of non checked box :

```
<input id="idea_store_ids_" type="checkbox" value="11" name="idea[store_ids][]"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, but a little more context (in the form of words and sentences) would be helpful...

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I have a list of check boxes with titles generated by a ruby model. Depending on the page, some check boxes are automatically selected. I would like to hide the other li's with check boxes and titles that are not selected.

Comment: Do you want to hide the `li` tags using jQuery or do you want to exclude those from the loop using Rails?

Comment: I want to hide the li tags that are not selected.

Comment: @anmaree on the client side using jQuery, right?

Comment: yes I want to hide the li tags that are not selected using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("input:not(:checked)").parent('li').hide();
```

Comment: I got it to work! I did this: $(function(){ $("input:not(:checked)").parent('li').hide()})